# Running sqlite tests on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, testing

I would like to run standard sqlite tests(TCL_Tests, which comes along with source code from official site). How can i build them and run on Android phone, i found no instructions about it.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use the Android NDK as these tests are implemented in 'C'.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771474/android-jni-is-there-any-way-c-code-can-directly-read-the-apps-sqlite-databas) seems to indicate it cannot be done.